# openlayers pinch zoom not working

Tags: openlayers, google-maps-api

I am interacting with a google map using openlayers3. On pinch zoom, the map throws an exception : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`

I am using Google Maps API 3.2 and OpenLayers 3.0.0.

**EDIT**

I notice the map is losing zoom property on pinch zoom:
`googleMap.getZoom()` now returns undefined. Thus the exception is thrown.

Comment: could you share your code, so people can see where the problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in calling `panTo` on google maps instead I used `setCenter()`.

```
openLayersView.on('change:center', function() {
        var center = ol.proj.transform(openLayersView.getCenter(), EPSG_3857, EPSG_4326);
        //googleMap.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(center[1], center[0])); <-- causes the exception
        googleMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(center[1], center[0]));
});
```